# THREE.js - Cannot load texture locally in Chrome Browser in Android device

Tags: android, google-chrome, three.js, textures

I have been trying to load textures for a WebGL application in a Chrome browser in an Android device

I came across a similar post [THREE.js - Can't load texture locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151026/three-js-cant-load-texture-locally/26506335#26506335) where a solution to load textures is given for Chrome which works only on a PC/laptop device

The flag --allow-file-access-from-files works on a laptop device as I can use the command line but how to do it on a mobile device?

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The Crosswalk projects embeds a Chromium webview and, by standard, will allow the loading of textures and models from files.You can compile your demo with Crosswalk by using this if you have a blacklisted gpu:
make_apk.py --package=org.crosswalkproject.yourproject \ --manifest=your_webgl_demo/manifest.json --xwalk-command-line='--ignore-gpu-blacklist'

The last part isn't necessary if your gpu supports webgl completely.
If you have problems though, replace the last part with 
--xwalk-command-line='--disable-web-security'
which will give you total access to files (with all the risks involved).

But the simplest method is to use a webserver on android to access files from 127.0.0.1:8080.
There are many free webservers on the playstore and I use them on a daily basis to test webgl demos on my device.