# Three.js MeshPhongMaterial Texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I'm trying to add a three js texture to a MeshPhongMaterial, but for some reason, I'm just getting a lit black box. I've been stuck on this for a while and can't seem to figure it out.

```
//Creates the cube and lighting effect
    function initCube() {
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var texture1 = loader.load("brick.jpg");
    cubeTexture = loader.load

     cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(3,3,3), new 
    THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0xffffff, map:texture1}));
    scene.add(cube);

    cube.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5); 
    cube.position.x =  0;

    //Adds light
    cubeLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFF0000 , 30, 1);
    cube.add(cubeLight);
    cubeLight.position.set(-0.5,-1,0); 
    scene.add(cubeLight);
    cubeLight.power =100;


    map.cubeLight = {
        light: cubeLight,
        added: true
    }

    //Adds second light
     cubeLight2 = new THREE.PointLight(0x6600ff , 1, 1);
    cube.add(cubeLight2);
    cubeLight2.position.set(0,1,0); 
    scene.add(cubeLight2);
    cubeLight2.power =100;

    map.cubeLight2 = {
        light: cubeLight2,
        added: true
    }

    }
```

Comment: Are you running a web server or are you trying to open the .html file directly in your browser? The latter being the most common reason for this not working, you should see warnings/errors in the browser console. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151026/three-js-cant-load-texture-locally .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the lights are inside the box. Choose greater values to position the lights outside of the box. And when placed them outside, you should also increase the `distance` value of your point lights. Otherwise, the lights won't light anything beyond a distance of 1 unit.

You could also add an ambient light to the scene, then you should definitely see, if the texture has loaded.

And a last thing: you added the the light twice to the scene. Once with `scene.add(cubeLight)` and once with `cube.add(cubeLight)`, while `cube` has already been added to the scene.